# SSH_login not prompting meterprepter?

Tags: ssh, metasploit

So Basically I am trying to create a SSH session in metasploit. session opens successfully when I do `sessions #`, it prints `[*] Starting interaction with 4...` but when I do a dir, no result or no output.

How I do it?

```
use scanner/ssh/ssh_login
set USERNAME username
set PASSWORD password
set RHOSTS x.x.x.x
exploit

[*] Command shell session 4 opened (x.x.x.x:x -> x.x.x.x:x) at 2019-06-18 13:29:53 -0400                                                    
[*] Scanned 1 of 1 hosts (100% complete)
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed

#sessions

Active sessions
===============

  Id  Name  Type           Information                                Connection                                                                           
  --  ----  ----           -----------                                ----------                                                                           
  4         shell windows  SSH x:x (x.x.x.x:22)  x.x.x.x -> x.x.x.x:22 (x.x.x.x)
```

Note: The IPs have been replaced with `x`

so now when I do:

```
msf5 auxiliary(scanner/ssh/ssh_login) > sessions 4
[*] Starting interaction with 4...

dir
```

Server OS:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]                                                                                                                     
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Client: `Kali Linux x64`

Comment: If you already have credentials, why would you want to perform an SSH login scan?

Answer (score 0):

While you do not produce enough information about the target system to be certain, this behavior is often seen with connections that are not actually meterpreter sessions (i.e. when a `nc` connects to your listener, for example).

My best guess would be that a firewall or antivirus on the host suspended the process after the initial connection because the meterpreter payload got detected.